D3 globe with country names label layer
I'm struggling to find any example of a D3 globe (or Globe-gl etc.) that has country names as a label layer.  I'm essentially looking for this demo
https://observablehq.com/@michael-keith/draggable-globe-in-d3
but with country names (ideally at the countries' geographical centre).  They should be zoomable with the globe, of course.  None of the 37 forks of the globe demo seem to have added this.  I'd appreciate any pointers at all.
I've added a pen in case that is easier:
<https://codepen.io/alhuber1502/pen/YzbGPMB>
Many thanks!

Here's a previous similar question. Though it uses an older version of D3. On a globe you may want to check the angular distance from current rotation to see if a label should be displayed. The text won't have the projection applied, so it won't change perspective as it rotates. Also centroid positioning is problematic, consider the US: Alaska really moves the centroid, or France: French Guiana moves the label into the Atlantic. Map annotation is a pain.

Effectively the solution is still svg.selectAll(null).data(features).enter().append("text").attr("d", path.centroid)... Then you need to apply the zoom transform / projection rotation the same as you do for the rest of the globe.

Thanks, Andrew!  I've added a pen in case that's easier to point to: https://codepen.io/alhuber1502/pen/YzbGPMB  I've looked at both the related question you linked to and your suggested solution, but am having trouble getting the labels to show.  I wondered whether it was possible to use the same meachnism the world borders are added also for the labels, would that work? Thanks!

@AndrewReid I got the labels to show https://codepen.io/alhuber1502/pen/YzbGPMB , sadly neither rotating, zoomable, or projected properly. Am I on the right path? Any help gratefully received!

Close, you update the country outlines with svg.selectAll("path").attr("d", path); on the drag even, but not the text, you need to apply the same logic you use to position the labels originally on the drag. I might be take a closer look tonight

To place the text on the globe you use the path method path.centroid. This returns the center of a path (as drawn, not geographically). This can be used to place the text as follows:
let text = svg.selectAll(null)
                  .data(data)
                  .enter()
                  .append("text")
                  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate("+path.centroid(d)+")"});

However, this doesn't work for features with no visible path (ie, features on the far side of the earth that aren't rendered). For this we need to do a check, otherwise the text will appear at [0,0]:
       .style("opacity", function(d) {
         if(path(d)) return 1; else return 0;
       })

This checks to see if any path data is created by the path generator, if not, we hide the text. If a path data isn't created, the feature isn't visible and shouldn't be labelled.
We update these every rotate event:
  text.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate("+path.centroid(d)+")"})
      .style("opacity", function(d) {
         if(path(d)) return 1; else return 0;
       })

We don't need to update the style every zoom event as we aren't rotating the earth (and hence hiding/revealing new paths).
I've taken your example (upped it to v7 for d3.json) and applied the above changes.


d3.json("https://static.observableusercontent.com/files/cbb0b433d100be8f4c48e19de6f0702d83c76df3def6897d7a4ccdb48d2f5f039bc3ae1141dd1005c253ca13c506f5824ae294f4549e5af914d0e3cb467bd8b0?response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename*%3DUTF-8%27%27world.json").then(function(data) {
  
    let width = 500;
    let height = 500;
    const sensitivity = 75;

    let projection = d3
      .geoOrthographic()
      .scale(250)
      .center([0, 0])
      .rotate([0, -30])
      .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

    const initialScale = projection.scale();
    let path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

    let svg = d3
      .select("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

    let globe = svg
      .append("circle")
      .attr("fill", "#EEE")
      .attr("stroke", "#000")
      .attr("stroke-width", "0.2")
      .attr("cx", width / 2)
      .attr("cy", height / 2)
      .attr("r", initialScale);

 

    let map = svg.append("g");

    map
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "countries")
      .selectAll("path")
      .data(data.features)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("class", (d) => "country_" + d.properties.name.replace(" ", "_"))
      .attr("d", path)
      .attr("fill", "white")
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .style("stroke-width", 0.3)
      .style("opacity", 0.8);
    
   let text = map
      .append("g")
      .selectAll("text")
      .data(data.features)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" +  path.centroid(d) + ")"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.properties.name; })
      .style("opacity", function(d) {
        if(path(d)) return 1; else return 0;
      })
   
 
   svg
      .call(
        d3.drag().on("drag", () => {
          const rotate = projection.rotate();
          const k = sensitivity / projection.scale();
          projection.rotate([
            rotate[0] + d3.event.dx * k,
            rotate[1] - d3.event.dy * k
          ]);
          path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);
          svg.selectAll("path").attr("d", path);
          text.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + path.centroid(d) + ")"; })
            .style("opacity", function(d) {
             if(path(d)) return 1; else return 0;
           })
        })
      )
      .call(
        d3.zoom().on("zoom", () => {
          if (d3.event.transform.k > 0.3) {
            projection.scale(initialScale * d3.event.transform.k);
            path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);
            svg.selectAll("path").attr("d", path);
            globe.attr("r", projection.scale());
            text.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + path.centroid(d) + ")"; })
          } else {
            d3.event.transform.k = 0.3;
          }
        })
      );   


    function placeText(d, projection, text) {
        d3.select(this)
          .attr("opacity", path(d) == NULL ? 1 : 0)
          .attr("transform",  "translate(" + path.centroid(d) + ")");
    }

})
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.9.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>



